# Testing whether a list has a specific form in R

Tags: r, function, arguments

First time question asker, so hopefully I'll do this right. Anyway, I'm writing a function in R which will take a list as one of its arguments. Specifically, the list needs to be of the form

```
list(c(x1,y1),c(x2,y2),...)
```

in other words a list of 2-element vectors representing Cartesian points. I'd like to do some error handling to detect whether a supplied list has that form. Any advice is appreciated. For example:

```
test <- function(points, ...){
    if( test for format goes here){
        return("Error: Invalid points list format")
    }
    main content
}
```

The points should be a list of arbitrary length, with each list element being a 2-element numeric vector.

Comment: Is the only requirement that each element have exactly two numbers?

Comment: Yes. I'm curious about the easiest way to catch all possible errors.

Comment: Is there a good reason that you are using a `list` for this function instead of a data-structure that is more easily compatible with this constraint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
all(lengths(points) == 2L & sapply(points, is.numeric))
```

The two tests are:

- `lengths(points) == 2L`

  Is each list length equal to 2
- `sapply(points, is.numeric)`

  Is each list element of the class `numeric`.

Comment: Thank you; I was hoping something like this existed. I was completely unfamiliar with the  `all` function.

Comment: You're welcome. You can also use `any` for "at least one" queries.

Comment: How did I miss this, haha